# Opening an excel file from button click on a windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

```
private void btnOpenReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(outputFilePath))
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("excel.exe", " /select, " + outputFilePath.Replace("\\\\", "\\")));
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question being asked here, or even a description of a problem. I just see some code that isn't even properly formatted. Can you [edit] to actually explain what the problem is with the code you posted, and then ask a question about what you want us to help you with?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you should just start the Excel file directly with property `UseShellExecute` to `true`, which is the default, and it will launch the default associated program, most likely Excel itself:

```
Process.Start(outputFilePath);
```

Another matter is why you are doing that `Replace`, but that's probably off-topic here.

Comment: thanks, it was helpful.

Comment: In modern .NET (Core and NET5+) UseShellExecute defaults to false, this code would work: `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(outputFilePath) { UseShellExecute = true });`